# CSS grid: on small devices the card does not display inside grid box

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

I'm new to CSS grid and I am trying to display three cards. As you can see in the picture below, on a tablet size the third card gets displayed on the next line, but it is not displayed inside the grid box, the top of the card on the second row overlaps the card on the first row. How can I fix this?

**how it looks**

[image]

**CSS**

```
.skills {
  background-color: #fff;
  .skills-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(20rem, 1fr));
    padding: 0 4rem;
    grid-gap: 3rem;

    .example-card {
      border-radius: 5px;
      margin-top: -10rem;
      margin-bottom: 15%;
      z-index: 6;
      padding: 0 !important;

      &__header {
        height: 10rem;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 600 !important;

        mat-card-subtitle {
          @include respond(tab-port) {
            display: none;
          }
        }
      }

      .card-img {
        height: 30rem;
        width: 100% !important;
        margin: 0 !important;

        @include respond(tab-land) {
          height: 20rem;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<section class="skills">
  <div class="skills-container">
    <mat-card class="example-card">
      <mat-card-header class="example-card__header">
        <mat-card-title>Front End Development</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>HTML, CSS, Javascript, Angular</mat-card-subtitle>
      </mat-card-header>
      <img class="card-img" mat-card-image src="/assets/images/front-end.jpg" alt="front-end">
    </mat-card>
    <mat-card class="example-card">
      <mat-card-header class="example-card__header">
        <mat-card-title>Back End Development</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>Node.js, Express, MongoDB, Socket.io,...</mat-card-subtitle>
      </mat-card-header>
      <img class="card-img" mat-card-image src="/assets/images/nodejs.jpeg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
    </mat-card>
    <mat-card class="example-card">
      <mat-card-header class="example-card__header">
        <mat-card-title>Web Design</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>CSS, SCSS, Responsive design,...</mat-card-subtitle>
      </mat-card-header>
      <img class="card-img" mat-card-image src="/assets/images/responsive.jpg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</section>
```

edit: It probably has to with the fact that the card have a margin-top of -10rem, How can I make sure that the card on the next line do not have this?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to remove the negative margin on .example_card

Comment: Yeah, I was kinda hoping I could keep that, because I want the top of the card to align with the end of the previous section. Is there a way to style the second row of the grid?

Comment: as a quick fix, try to give the negative margin to the .skills-container